# C# hybird Winforms / console app returns to cmd prompt

Tags: c#

I have seen many examples of a hybrid gui/cli app for C#. I have implemented such an app, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to prevent the .exe, when run on the command line, from not returning back to the prompt right away.

```
    //defines for commandline output     
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
    private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

    [STAThreadAttribute]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // load cli
        // redirect console output to parent process;         
        // must be before any calls to Console.WriteLine()         
        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);

        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            //loads gui
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new form_Main());
        }
        else
        {

            cli_main cli = new cli_main();
            cli.start_cli(args);

            Console.WriteLine("finished");

            System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
            Application.Exit();

        }
    }
```

I get the following output

```
C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\test\test\bin\Debug>test.exe -param1 test 
-param2 test2

C:\Users\john\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\test\test\test\bin\Debug>Output was successful. File saved as: c:\test\test.html
finished
```

The line "finished" is a string I output when I know I have reach end of my main code... this works fine in Winforms, my project is Winforms and I started it as a gui but now I am trying to make it hybrid gui/cli

And it seems to be running my main code and threads I see them in debugging and it creates my final output file...

I just am puzzled as to how to keep the .exe when executed from cmd line with it's parameters, to not return to the command prompt?? And have it wait with a blinking cursor, then output the line about the html file and then the line "finished", then finally go back to the command prompt.

I've tried numerous things like removing

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
Application.Exit();
```

and instead of using `Application.Exit();` use `Environment.Exit(0);` but it always returns to the command prompt right away, also I tried putting in sleep for 5 secs after the line

```
cli.start_cli(args);
```

but that didn't work either, I guess I don't understand how it can return to command prompt right away and it hasn't even it the line

```
Console.WriteLine("finished");
```

Comment: I just gave up on trying to create a hybrid CLI and GUI .exe , if i keep project as winform i get this issue above, if i keep it as console app, then i would get a cmd window popping up, which i got a workaround for but would still pop up for sec. so i just went with 2 .exe , 1 for gui 1 for cli and then created a .dll lib to share main code between the 2.

Answer (score 6):

FWIW, I tried the first approach as well.  I ended up just hiding the console window using:

```
IntPtr handle = GetConsoleWindow();
if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    ShowWindow(handle, 0);  // 0=SW_HIDE
}
```

This completely hides the window, even from the Taskbar.  It flashes for a brief second but that's acceptable in my case